# Template Inheritance/Extending Layout does not work in laravel

Tags: laravel

My problem is that template inheritance does not work for some views.

This is my template (layout.blade.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PoetryCollective</title>
    <link href="{{ asset('bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
    </head>
    <body>

        </div>
        <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 line logotitle">
                        <img alt="logotitle" src="{{ asset('images/poetryfont.png') }}"></img>  

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 line">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs mynav navbar-right">
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><?php echo link_to('/users/signup', 'SignUp');?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="logotitle">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 rightlogo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default mainnav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li  role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Write poems</a></li>
                            <li  role="presentation"><a href="#">Read Poems</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find a poem">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 content">
                        @yield('content')


                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras maximus in velit nec mattis. Morbi auctor massa vitae lorem molestie aliquam. Vivamus bibendum mi at eros fermentum, et gravida risus euismod. Quisque eu nisl vel urna placerat imperdiet nec in tortor. Morbi interdum pulvinar odio, eu pharetra massa varius vitae. Pellentesque suscipit felis ante, at dapibus felis luctus quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean feugiat luctus erat, id facilisis mi suscipit quis. Donec eu erat sed leo volutpat rutrum. Suspendisse aliquam pretium eleifend. Curabitur nec volutpat ex. In interdum tortor id enim efficitur, ut porttitor lacus consectetur. Mauris blandit mollis neque, eget tincidunt ex hendrerit non. Donec sed ligula eu enim feugiat sollicitudin. Sed facilisis at mauris in rutrum.

                        </p>

                        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

                        <p>


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent purus justo, consectetur at blandit id, porttitor vitae nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer efficitur nulla eros. Aliquam eleifend venenatis sapien, sit amet lacinia dolor rhoncus quis. Fusce aliquam ullamcorper nulla at iaculis. Pellentesque suscipit, mi ut rhoncus sodales, elit arcu suscipit ex, a tempor eros quam quis ipsum. Vestibulum interdum rutrum faucibus. Aliquam vel feugiat mi, id vulputate nulla. Aliquam dapibus dolor eu risus tempus posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer in malesuada leo, ac commodo diam.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam bibendum lectus nec felis tempus, a fermentum enim condimentum. Etiam magna nulla, bibendum egestas dictum vitae, rhoncus at lorem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla vestibulum vel lectus pharetra lobortis. Pellentesque lorem odio, consectetur in ultricies sagittis, facilisis at ante. Phasellus at sagittis nunc. Mauris hendrerit velit libero, vitae finibus augue rhoncus eget. Ut tincidunt pharetra arcu, ac fermentum nisi faucibus in. Nulla molestie vestibulum ligula, eget ultricies ex dictum id. Quisque scelerisque dictum lorem. Ut euismod blandit sem, sit amet tempor nulla sollicitudin aliquam. Nulla egestas feugiat fringilla.

Etiam id molestie neque, non malesuada enim. Aenean blandit interdum ligula, nec gravida dui. Nam lectus nisi, pulvinar at dolor et, dignissim maximus odio. Quisque sed congue velit, pellentesque fermentum dui. Mauris sed varius sem, nec dapibus est. Nulla suscipit enim diam, quis gravida quam placerat vel. Integer a dui ornare, hendrerit urna sed, sollicitudin enim. Phasellus id ante a sapien dictum hendrerit fermentum nec lectus. Integer elementum orci volutpat viverra interdum.

Fusce eget orci ornare, varius libero in, sodales nisl. Aenean at scelerisque eros. Nunc ut viverra neque, ut posuere libero. Maecenas in massa venenatis, mattis mauris. 


                        </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 sidebar">
                    <h3>Sidebar</h3>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 footer">
                <p class="credit">
                    Fontdesign in Logo by Sergiy S. Tkachenko</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{{ asset('bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/production.min.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Oddly, this view works and loads/extends the layout template:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
{{ $poems }}
@stop
```

But this one does not work and not load the template but only displays the content of itself:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')

<?php
echo "<p>Signing up</p>";

echo Form::open(array('url' => '/users/signup'));
echo Form::label('username', 'Username');
echo Form::text('username');
echo Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address');
echo Form::text('email');
echo Form::label('Password');
echo Form::password('password');
// echo Form::password('password1', 'Password confirmation');
echo Form::close();

if(!empty ($errors))
{
    foreach ($erros->all() as $error)
    {
        echo '<div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
@stop
```

I just can't figure out why the one loads the template and the other one doesn't. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please, show your controller

Comment: `foreach ($erros->all() as $error)` to `foreach ($errors->all() as $error)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of those situations where you're making a few unstated (possibly unrealized) assumptions about how the template system works.  I'm going to point out what's confusing about your question, and hopefully that points you in the correct direction.

There's **two** template systems in Laravel.  One, named blade, uses syntax like this

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    La de {{$da}}
@stop
```

The second, less used, system is a basic PHP template system.  i.e., a PHP file is included via a class method, and you have access to the full PHP system.  It uses syntax that looks like this

```
<h1>This is a template</h1>
La de <?php echo $da; ?>
```

Laravel decides which engine to use based on the template's file name.  If you say

```
View::make('example');
```

and name your template `app/view/example.blade.php`, then Laravel will render your template using the blade system.  If you name the template `app/view/example.php`, Laravel will render your template using the PHP system.

**Important**: Only the blade system supports template inheritance.  i.e. there's no equivalent to `@extends` and `@section` for the PHP template.  You can simulate this via other means, but there's no inheritance concept in the PHP templates.

In your question, you didn't include your template's names, so we can't tell if they're being rendered by blade or by PHP.

<s>Also, in your second template, you're mixing blade and PHP syntax.  You can't just switch over to PHP with `<?php` in a blade template.</s>

```
@section('content')

<?php
echo "<p>Signing up</p>";
```

This is just a guess, but I assume this second template has a `blade.php` extension, meaning Laravel is rendering it with blade, which is why your PHP code isn't rendered.  The best thing for you to do would be convert your PHP template in a blade template.  i.e. this

```
<?php
echo "<p>Signing up</p>";

echo Form::open(array('url' => '/users/signup'));
echo Form::label('username', 'Username');
```

Becomes this

```
<p>Signing up</p>
{{Form::open(array('url' => '/users/signup'))}}
{{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
```

Comment: You can use raw php tags in blade template, I think problem in another things

Comment: Huh, learned something new there.  I don't think I like that feature.  Regardless -- what are your templates named?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, but your code makes no sense to me.

If you are using blade template you would be better suited using the following:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

<p>Signing up</p>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/users/signup')) }}
{{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
{{ Form::text('username') }}
{{ Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address') }}
{{ Form::text('email') }}
{{ Form::label('Password') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

@if(!empty ($errors))
    @foreach ($erros->all() as $error)
        <div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
    @endforeach
@endif
@stop
```

Much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If one of them is working and the other one is not, you should check the following:

1) The location of the file. eg if it's in the 'layouts' folder, you need to prefix the folder name:

```
    @extends('layouts.foo')
```

2) The file name has the extension *.blade.php* eg **foo.blade.php** (not **foo.php**)

3) The actual file name, you may have named it incorrectly, check the spelling and extension of the file